# AWS Lambda Docker Custom Python Library (Runtime.ImportModuleError)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy a custom machine learning library on Lambda using a [Lambda docker image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html).

The image is looking approximately as follows:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

CMD mkdir -p /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace

# Copy necessary files (e.g. setup.py and library/)
COPY ...

# Install library and requirements
RUN pip3 install . --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Copy lambda scripts
COPY ... "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/"

# CMD [ my_script.my_handler ]
```

Thus, it installs a local python package including dependencies to LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT (/var/task). The CMD (handler) is overriden in AWS, e.g. `preprocessing.lambda_handler`.

The container works fine for handlers that DO NOT use the custom python library (on AWS and locally). However, trying to use the custom library on AWS, it fails with `Runtime.ImportModuleError` claiming that `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'MY_HANDLER': No module named 'MY_LIBRARY'"`.

Everything works when running the container locally with the [runtime interface emulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html). The file-level permissions should be ok as well.

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here: There was no problem with the Docker container itself. The problem was that **Lambda references docker image versions via their SHA, not the tag**, thus update to the tag did not update the container of the functions. To update the container image, you have to use something like

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $MY_FN --image-uri $MY_URI
```